# Publishing ArcGIS Server service without cache does not show map on mobile?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cache, arcgis-android, arcgis-ios

We're publishing a whole country data set using ArcGIS Server and we need to display it on web and on mobile applications.

The issue we're facing is that the data is too big so we're not creating cache while publishing the service and here we're facing a strange issue i.e. the service is not showing map on mobile when we try to publish it using mobile SDK's while the service do show map on web when we use ArcGIS JavaScript API.

The question is, how we can make it possible to show maps on mobile if we don't want to create cache while publishing the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we were looking around for different solutions, we thought there must be a difference in adding a cached and a non-cached layer. And here we got the solution.

We were trying to add **ArcGIS Tiled Map Service layer**

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"]; 
AGSTiledMapServiceLayer* layer = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL: url];
```

Instead we need to add **Dynamic map service layer** as below

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer"];

AGSDynamicMapServiceLayer* layer = [AGSDynamicMapServiceLayer dynamicMapServiceLayerWithURL: url];
```

[Here](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/objective-c/guide/dynamic-map-service-layer.htm) is the official documentation